# How can enable/disable auto complete options for ACE editor?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ace-editor

I'd like to enable/disable autocomplete options of the ACE editor by pressing the keys 'ctrl+spacebar'.

Below mentioned is my code which I am using

```
  highlightEditor(editor, codeEditorElmRef) {
const element = codeEditorElmRef;
  const editorOptions: Partial<ace.Ace.EditorOptions> = {
  highlightActiveLine: true,
  showLineNumbers: true,
  highlightSelectedWord: true,
  fontSize: 12,
  tabSize: 2
};
const codeEditor: ace.Ace.Editor = ace.edit(element, editorOptions);

  codeEditor.setOptions({
    enableBasicAutocompletion: true,
    enableSnippets: true,
    enableLiveAutocompletion: true
  });


  console.log("153 else statement")
  codeEditor.setOptions({
    enableBasicAutocompletion: false,
    enableSnippets: false,
    enableLiveAutocompletion: false

let currentObj = this;
// key bindings to ace editor
```

codeEditor.commands.addCommand({
name: 'turn-on/off',
bindKey: { win: "Ctrl-space", mac: "Cmd-space" },
exec: function (editor) {
currentObj.highlightEditor(editor, codeEditorElmRef);
}
});

```
editor.editorID = codeEditor.id;
codeEditor.resize(true);
this.aceCodeEditors.push(codeEditor);
```

}

Please help me in this.